# iOS some problems during download multiple images and update UIProgressView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, download, uiprogressview

I have this 3 classes.

- [MyViewController.m (click to see code)](http://pastebin.com/G4hHM0Xc)
- [MySync.m (click to see code)](http://pastebin.com/TPBVzjUv)
- [ImageDownload.m (click to see code)](http://pastebin.com/GXCz2SCc)

When I download a image, I try to update the UIProgressView in my UIViewController, but the update are delayed, and I see a strange problem (see the blank space in attach image).

When all downloads are complete and execute the method "syncComplete" of "MyViewController", the method "dismissAlertView" is not triggered :S

[image]

I hope somebody can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that syncComplete is the one calling dismissAlertView, make sure iI is calling to the UI thread (main thread).  Something like this if you use GCD:

```
dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue (),  ^{
// call the dismissAlertView method here
});
```